Read large Csv map data and send by HTTP
Hi I have large CSV file (20GB) ~ 100 kk rows to process. CSV structure is simple, there are 4 columns var1,var2,var3,timestamp(yyyy-MM-dd) - all of them are string.
So i should read csv row by row then prepare request(convert date to datetime) and send request to server. I cannot send bulk data.
import pandas as pd
import string
from datetime import datetime
import aiohttp
import asyncio

url_data = 'http://localhost:8080/test'
template = string.Template(("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
    <const1>CONST1</const1>
    <const2>CONST2</const2>
    <var1>${VAR1}</var1>
    <timestamp>${DATETIME}</timestamp>
    <const3>CONST3</const3>
    <var2>${VAR2}</var2>
    <var3>${VAR3}</var3>
</request>"""))


async def process():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for chunk in pd.read_csv('test.csv', chunksize=50000):
            await asyncio.gather(asyncio.create_task(send(session, chunk)))


async def send(session, chunk):
    for index, row in chunk.iterrows():
        date = datetime.strptime(row['DATETIME'], '%Y-%m-%d')
        row['DATETIME'] = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        await session.post(url=url_data, data=template.safe_substitute(row))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(process())


I have prepared a Python script and I would like some advice on whether it can be further optimized for speed

why use pandas? if you are just going to iterate row by row then pandas will only slow you down.

what you suggest?

I suggest not to use pandas. You aren't doing anything here which pandas is designed to do. Why did you use pandas to begin with?

In any case, the bottleneck is probably I/O, so it may not ultimately matter, but it is a strange use of pandas

Would it be better to use Dask instead of pandas?

No. You should use the csv module.

So the best option is to use bellow code?
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
            process()


@J.Doe, whether the csv modue is faster than Pandas depends on the use case. For your application, Panda's memory overhead will matter more, but even then probably won't slow your program down. Still, the csv module and reader or DictReader seem the better option, at least for simplicity/clarity. BTW, does your script work? You didn't really indicate if you're satisfied with it.

Looking at the code I see you aren't posting to server concurrently. Here is an example how you can do it with asyncio/aiohttp. You can play with the parameters (the number in asyncio.Semaphore and/or the point where you gather created tasks):
import asyncio
import csv
import string
from datetime import datetime

import aiohttp

url_data = "https://httpbin.org/post"  # <-- example URL

limit = asyncio.Semaphore(3)  # <-- limit concurent tasks to 3

template = string.Template(
    """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
    <const1>CONST1</const1>
    <const2>CONST2</const2>
    <var1>${VAR1}</var1>
    <timestamp>${DATETIME}</timestamp>
    <const3>CONST3</const3>
    <var2>${VAR2}</var2>
    <var3>${VAR3}</var3>
</request>"""
)


async def process():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        with open("your_file.csv", "r") as f_in:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)

            tasks = set()
            for row_no, row in enumerate(reader):
                tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(send(session, row)))

                if row_no % 10:  # <--- every 10 tasks wait for them to finish
                    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
                    tasks = set()

            # the remaining:
            if tasks:
                await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def send(session, row):
    d = datetime.strptime(row["DATETIME"], "%Y-%m-%d")
    row["DATETIME"] = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    async with limit:
        resp = await session.post(url=url_data, data=template.safe_substitute(row))

        print(await resp.text())  # <-- print response (just for debugging purposes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(process())


Split the CSV files into even smaller files and send them in smaller batches than what you have here

they are sending it row by row, it cannot get any smaller.
